# Get new row id, after insert query in sql

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have the following insert query:

```
    string InsertQuery = string.Format("insert into tblUsers (FirstName, LastName, Email, UserPassword, Area, BirthDate, AboutMe, Phone, RideExp, RegisterDate, Gender) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},'{5}','{6}',{7}, {8},'{9}')"
        , FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, AreaID, BirthDate, AboutMe, RideExp, RegisterDate, Gender);
```

My question is if there is any easy way to get the new `row-id` for this specific new line?

Wish for help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim dbs as DAO.Database
Dim TranID as Long
TranID = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select @@Identity")(0)
```

This question has good information on its use.  [SELECT @@IDENTITY not scoped by DB object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942781/select-identity-not-scoped-by-db-object)